# Technology stack for a Linux hosted web application

Tags: linux, web-apps, web-development, mysql

I'm looking for suggestions on a technology stack to use for a simple web application to track expenses that (a) must be hosted on a Ubuntu server and (b) use a MySQL database.  I've been asked to provide suggestions, but not actually work on the project.

The company I work for has volunteered to do some pro-bono development for a non-profit.  The non-profit needs a very simple web application that tracks expenses by office location (they have 5) and expense category (~25 categories).  So, basically a crud application with a few different business objects.  We will then need to do some very basic reporting.

The only developers assigned to work on this project are a pair of junior developers who have ONLY worked in the .NET stack (MVC4, WCF, SQL Server).  I floated the Mono idea, but that was shot down, and not an option.

Any recommendations would be very helpful.  I've been looking for a solution where I can find a working example (open source) online to build upon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of the LAMP stack being, in my case:
Linux (you've got Ubuntu)
Apache
MySQL (one of the requirements)
PHP

There's loads of free IDEs out there for PHP, you can use Eclipse, Netbeans or many others.  I personally use PHPStorm, but it's not free.

On top of the LAMP stack, git for source control; but you could use whatever you currently use probably.

I'd go for the [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) framework as it's easy to use, doesn't tie you in too much to the principles of MVC patterns and works simply as a zip download rather than needing to setup and configure the likes of composer.

Answer (score 1):

I like this:

- Python
- Django
- PostgresSQL
- git
- pyCharm (IDE)

Some new team mates worked with .net and c# before and now like python very much. They don't want to go back to c#.

There are many Django packages ready to use: https://www.djangopackages.com/